# How to set an API operation as deprecated with Restler?

Tags: php, restler

I am using Restler to provide a REST API in a code written in PHP and I would like to set an operation as deprecated in the API.
I use the Restler API Explorer for documenting/browsing the API.

The Restler API Explorer is based on Swagger UI and it looks that Swagger UI supports that:

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/289
- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/pull/1740

Is it possible to do the same thing with Restler? How? Or do I need to open an issue to request this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now you have to use the description to mark a an api as deprecated. When we complete the `swagger2.0` implementation you will have a better way to deal with this

Comment: Thank you. This is the issue about that on GitHub, right? https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/529